Concurrency error in .NET with SQL Server and Entity Framework
I am experiencing a concurrency error when trying to update my Advert entity. Am I doing something wrong?
Context: each advert must have one or more photos. And my logic would be when the front sends the new images, I delete the old ones and add the new ones.
Am I doing something wrong?
Here is my code:
public async Task<ResponseModel<AdvertDto>> Update(AdvertUpdateDto advertUpdateDto, Guid id) {
    var response = new ResponseModel<AdvertDto>();

    // Busca o anúncio existente no banco de dados
    var advert = await _context.Adverts
        .Include(a => a.Imagens)
        .Include(a => a.Opcionais)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);

    if (advert == null) {
        response.Dados = null;
        response.Mensagem = "Auncio não encontrado";
        return response;
    }

    
    _context.Photos.RemoveRange(advert.Imagens);


    var novasImagens = advertUpdateDto.Imagens
        .Select(url => new Photo(url.Url, url.Chave))
        .ToList();
    await _context.Photos.AddRangeAsync(novasImagens);

    try {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    } catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) {
        throw new Exception("Erro de concorrência: as informações foram modificadas por outro usuário.");
    }

    response.Mensagem = "Anuncio alterado com sucesso";


    return response;
}

public sealed class Advert
{
    [Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public int AnoModelo { get; set; }
    public string Cor { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public int Preco { get; set; }
    public string Portas { get; set; }
    public int Quilometragem { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Placa { get; set; }
    public string Cambio { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)] public DateTime DataCricao { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)] public DateTime? DataAtualizacao { get; set; }
    public Condition Condicao { get; set; } = Condition.REQUESTED;
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public bool? Destaque { get; set; }
    public Guid UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public User Usuario { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Photo>? Imagens { get; set; } = [];
    public ICollection<Optional>? Opcionais { get; set; } = [];
    [Timestamp] public byte[] Version { get; set; }

    private Advert() {}

    public Advert(string tipo, string marca, string modelo, int anoModelo, string cor, string cep,
        string cidade, string estado, int preco, string portas, int quilometragem, string descricao, string placa,
        string cambio, DateTime dataAtualizacao, Condition condicao, string slug, bool? destaque, Guid usuarioId,
        User usuario,
        ICollection<Photo>? imagens, ICollection<Optional>? opcionais)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Tipo = tipo;
        Marca = marca;
        Modelo = modelo;
        AnoModelo = anoModelo;
        Cor = cor;
        Cep = cep;
        Cidade = cidade;
        Estado = estado;
        Preco = preco;
        Portas = portas;
        Quilometragem = quilometragem;
        Descricao = descricao;
        Placa = placa;
        Cambio = cambio;
        DataAtualizacao = dataAtualizacao;
        Condicao = condicao;
        Slug = slug;
        Destaque = destaque;
        UsuarioId = usuarioId;
        Usuario = usuario;
        Imagens = imagens;
        Opcionais = opcionais;
    }
}


Do you have code that actually sets the value of Version property to anything other than the null default? In SQL Server no two null values are equal, i.e.: select 1 where null = null would return no rows, which will cause EF to throw a DBConcurrencyException because it cannot match the current record's version against that in the database row.

good afternoon. Thanks for the answer. I changed the code, if you can check again. I changed the Version field and the service. Does it still generate the error? How to deal with this? I just want to remove the old images and add the ones coming from the client.

The exception contains information, don't swallow it, take a look at it.
